# django admin : CharField display doesn't reflect the database value

Tags: django-admin

```
IS_ACTIVE = (
    (0,'Inactive'),
    (1,'Active'),
)

class Pagerule(models.Model):
    pagehash = models.CharField(max_length=32,editable=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=False, choices=IS_ACTIVE, default=0)
    page_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PAGETYPE, blank=False, verbose_name="Page Type")
```

When a `Pagerule` is saved, the choice on `IsActive` field gets through correctly as 1 for `Active` and 0 for `Inactive` but on being re-opened, the drop-down seems always pointing to the first entry in `IS_ACTIVE` i.e. `Inactive`, irrespective of the corresponding `is_active` value in DB.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be matter of type-mismatch.

IS_ACTIVE = (
    (`False`,'Inactive'),
    (`True`,'Active'),
)
is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=False, choices=IS_ACTIVE, default=`False`)